# Can't overwrite field declarations without initialiser

Tags: typescript, es2022

I have a module which includes the following:

```js
class FooBar {
    type: string;
}

class Foo extends FooBar {
    type: 'foo';
}

class Bar extends FooBar {
    type: 'bar';
}
```

(See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/EpicWink/6718c422793a7e592f196f23889b788a) for the full module, as well as supporting config)

When I compile with `tsc`, I get the error:

```
main.ts:14:5 - error TS2612: Property 'type' will overwrite the base property in 'FooBar'. If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration.

14     type: 'foo';
       ~~~~

main.ts:20:5 - error TS2612: Property 'type' will overwrite the base property in 'FooBar'. If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration.

20     type: 'bar';
       ~~~~


Found 2 errors in the same file, starting at: main.ts:14
```

However I need those fields to not be annotated with `declare` and to not have an initialiser (for class validation/transformation purposes).

The error only appears when I set the Typescript target to ES2022 (it works with ES2021 and earlier)

Answer (score 0):

Annotating the `type` in the base class as `abstract` avoids the error:

```js
abstract class FooBar {
    abstract type: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error indicates, you need to add an initializer:

`type = "foo" as const`

Tho this should suffice, TS really want you to make properties `abstract` if you want the type to be override as well.

Comment: Setting an initialiser is not an option in my case, as the value would then be defined on instantiation, breaking validation. I think that's fine in my specific case because I must have `type` provided to discriminate between the possible subclasses.